# Как правильно записать регулярное выражение (JS)?

Tags: javascript

Есть задача:

> После ввода пароля нужно проверить его на требования безопасности. В
>   пароле должна быть минимум 6 символов, 1 спецсимвол (!@#$%^&*(),.), 1
>   заглавная буква, 2 цифры, недопустимо использование букв подряд из
>   abcde... алфавита, недоспустимо использование цифр подряд 123... в
>   любом месте пароля

Сделал нечто подобное:

```
pass.match(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.+[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*(),.])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*(),.]{6,}$/)
```

В результате работает все, кроме пунктов:

> недопустимо использование букв подряд из abcde... алфавита,
>   недоспустимо использование цифр подряд 123... в любом месте пароля

Comment: я не  помню, что в js с негативным подглядыванием вперед, а так смотрите по ссылке. Но я не хотел бы быть вашим пользователем  https://regex101.com/r/hpBkiE/1

Comment: @splash58, спасибо за ответ, подобного результата я уже добивался, возможно я не совсем корректно изъяснился. Необходима немного другая логика. В пароле можно использовать символы 385 или 12 или 23, а вот 123... нельзя, так же и с буквами bac, ab, bc можно, а abc... нельзя и так далее

Comment: по-моему, написать что-то типа [0-9](\1+1) :) нельзя, придется все варианты перебирать :(

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.+[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*(),.])(?!.*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])(?!.*[0-9][0-9])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*(),.]{6,}$/
```

Спасибо @splash58, ничего лучше, чем этот вариант к сожалению найти не удалось, этот вариант самый близкий к истине